# How to split this string in Java regex?

Tags: java, regex, split

This is the string:

```
String strPro = "(a0(a1)(a2 and so on)...(aN))";
```

Content in a son-() may be "", or just the value of strPro, or like that pattern, recursively, so a sub-() is a sub-tree.

Expected result:

```
str1 is "a0(a1)"
str2 is "(a2 and so on)"
...
strN is "(aN)"
```

str1, str2, ..., strN are e.g. elements in an Array

How to split the string?

Comment: Regex is not appropriate for parsing recursive grammars such as this.  You need a real parser for this.

Comment: thanks. but even not working for just splitting strPro a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring()` to get rid of the outer paranthesis, and then split it using *lookbehind* and *lookahead* (`?<=` and `?=`):

```
String strPro = "(a0(a1)(a2 and so on)(aN))";
String[] split = strPro.substring(1, strPro.length() - 1).split("(?<=\\))(?=\\()");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

This prints

> [a0(a1), (a2 and so on), (aN)]

Comment: It works well; Nice, wonderful, splendid, my English expr is poor, but thank you, Keppil

Comment: (S(B1)(B2(B21)(B22)(B23)))  -->  I need only S(B1) and B2(B21)(B22)(B23)), first level, not four elements, how can I reach this?

Comment: @droidpiggy: You can use `split("(?<=\\))(?=\\()", 2)`, where the `2` is the maximum length of the result. This will only apply the splitting pattern once.